# SCRIPT ERROR: @essentialmode/server/main.lua:126: attempt to call a nil value (global 'registerUser')

Tags: lua, fivem

I have a problem on my FiveM server in GTAV. So, I have essentialmode script.

After a new user come out to server, this happen:

```
[script:essentialmode] > fn (@essentialmode/server/main.lua:126)
```

My main.lua configuration from 111 line:

```
RegisterServerEvent('es:firstJoinProper')
AddEventHandler('es:firstJoinProper', function()
    local Source = source
    Citizen.CreateThread(function()
        local id
        for k,v in ipairs(GetPlayerIdentifiers(Source))do
            if string.sub(v, 1, string.len(settings.defaultSettings.identifierUsed .. ":")) == (settings.defaultSettings.identifierUsed .. ":") then
                id = v
                break
            end
        end

        if not id then
            DropPlayer(Source, "SteamID not found, please try reconnecting with Steam open.")
        else
            registerUser(identifier, Source)
            justJoined[Source] = true
    
        end

        return
    end)
end)
```

Any thoughts to solve this problem?

Comment: try RegisterUser as all other functions in your code start with capital letters.  if that doesn't help find out what registerUser is and why you think that's a function

Comment: @Piglet I changed registerUser to RegisterUser in every lua file where is formula registerUser and still have:

[script:essentialmode] SCRIPT ERROR: @essentialmode/server/main.lua:126: attempt to call a nil value (global 'RegisterUser')
[script:essentialmode] > fn (@essentialmode/server/main.lua:126)

Comment: I don't know why it is function, but on branch release from developer essentialmode - he has same script configuration. Here's login.lua - there's explain how this function works:

Comment: -- This gets called whenever a user spawns for the first time in the server, it basically loads the player
function RegisterUser(identifier, source)
 local Source = source
 db.doesUserExist(identifier, function(exists)
  if exists then
   LoadUser(identifier, Source, false)
  else
   local license
   for k,v in ipairs(GetPlayerIdentifiers(Source))do
    if string.sub(v, 1, string.len("license:")) == "license:" then
     license = v
     break
    end
   end

   db.createUser(identifier, license, function()
    LoadUser(identifier, Source, true)
   end)
  end
 end)
end

Comment: it is defined in login.lua as a global function. if it is a nil value in your main.lua login.lua has not been executed yet. make sure it is befor you attempt to call registerUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know FiveM but a quick websearch yielded this:

https://github.com/rudzboy/fivem-essentialmode/search?q=server_script

which contains stuff like this:

```
-- Server
server_script 'server/classes/player.lua'
server_script 'server/classes/groups.lua'
server_script 'server/player/login.lua'
server_script 'server/main.lua'
server_script 'server/util.lua'
```

and this:

https://docs.fivem.net/docs/scripting-reference/resource-manifest/resource-manifest/

You most likely did not execute login.lua which defines registerUser, befor calling it in main.lua

You'll need a resource manifest that executes those files in the correct order like in the examples given above and in the documentation.